# PHP doc A echos PHP doc B, but PHP doc B can't read session from document A

Tags: php, session

I've started to pick up PHP again, but I'm stuck with a small detail which I just can't wrap my head around.

So, I have a PHP document called `home.php` and a PHP document `header.php`. The header.php file is to import HTML/PHP for the page header in every 'view' page. This is done as follows:

**Snippet of home.php**

```
<div id="main-wrapper" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
    <!-- Header row -->
    <?php
        echo file_get_contents("header.php");
    ?>
</div>
```

This mostly works, but in my header.php I have the following:

**Snippet of header.php**

```
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a id="li-username" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="profile.php">Profile</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="mytrades.php">Manage trades</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </li>
```

The problem here is that the value of `li-username` is empty.. meaning the 'inner PHP' can't read the session of the `home.php` page.

Important is that it **does** work if I put the contents of header.php on the right place of home.php, but that is what I try to avoid since I will be reusing the header.php in other php files...

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Use `include`, `require` or `file_get_contents('http://www.fullurl.com/header.php')`

Comment: @DarkBee changing `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` to  `<?php require_once 'header.php'; echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` did not solve the problem :(

Comment: You need to change the `file_get_contents` as this just grabs the content of a file rather than interpret the `PHP` inside it

Comment: you need session_start() - also use require_once('header.php');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing your home.php file

```
 <?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['username'] = 'Test';
 ?>

<div id="main-wrapper" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-12">
<!-- Header row -->
<?php
    include("header.php");
?>
 </div>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!